# SQLAlchemy filter based on comparison of own columns

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm looking for essentially the equivalent of Django's F() expression for SQLAlchemy
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model

I have a model:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
  total = db.Column(db.Integer())
  previous_total = db.Column(db.Integer())
```

And I want to query for my_models where total > previous_total.
In Django that would look like `my_models = MyModel.objects.filter(total__gt=F('previous_total'))`

I've been really struggling with the SQLAlchemy docs, in part because most of the docs seem structured towards using `session.query` API whereas the codebase I'm working with is using `MyModel.query`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve rows where `total > previous_total` the SQLAlchemy query would be

```py
my_query = session.query(MyModel).filter(MyModel.total > MyModel.previous_total)
```

or if you are using something that injects the session into the model class, like flask-sqlalchemy:

```py
my_query = MyModel.filter(MyModel.total > MyModel.previous_total)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's very annoying how much time I spent googling something so simple 